# Adding a status (file integrity)check to a cbr cbz converting bash script

Tags: bash, zip, 7zip, rar

First post, so Hi! Let me start by saying I'm a total noob regarding programming. I understand very basic stuff, but when it comes to checking exit codes or what the adequate term is, I'm at a loss. Apparently my searchfoo is really weak in this area, I guess it's a question of terminology.

*Thanks in advance for taking your time to reading this/answering my question!*

**Description**: I found a [script](http://comicrack.cyolito.com/forum/13-scripts/30013-cbr2cbz-rar-to-zip-conversion-for-linux) that converts/repack .cbr files to .cbz files. These files are basically your average [rar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rar) and [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) files, however renamed to another extension as they are used for (comic)book applications such as [comicrack](http://comicrack.cyolito.com/), [qcomicbook](http://qcomicbook.org/overview) and what not. Surprisingly enough there no cbr -> cbz converters out there. The advantages of .cbz is besides escaping the *proprietary* rar file format, that one can store the metadata from [Comic Vine](http://www.comicvine.com/) with e. g [comictagger](https://code.google.com/p/comictagger/).

**Issue**: Sometimes the repackaging of the files doesn't end well and would hopefully be alleviated by a integrity check & another go. I modified said script slightly to use [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net) as it can both pack/unpack [7z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z), zip-files and [some others](http://www.7-zip.org), i. e great for options. p7zip can test the archive by:

```
7z t comicfile.cbz tmpworkingdir
```

I guess it's a matter of using if & else here(?) to check the integrity and then give it another go, if there are any error.

### Question/tl;dr: What would be the "best"/adequate approach to add a integrity file check to the script below?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Source: http://comicrack.cyolito.com/forum/13-scripts/30013-cbr3cbz-rar-to-zip-conversion-for-linux
echo "Converting CBRs to CBZs"

# Set the "field separator" to something other than spaces/newlines" so that spaces
# in the file names don't mess things up. I'm using the pipe symbol ("|") as it is very
# unlikely to appear in a file name.
IFS="|"

# Set working directory where to create the temp dir. The user you are using must have permission
# to write into this directory.
# For performance reasons I'm using ram disk (/dev/shm/) in Ubuntu server.
WORKDIR="/dev/shm/"

# Set name for the temp dir. This directory will be created under WORDDIR
TEMPDIR="cbr2cbz"

# The script should be invoked as "cbr2cbz {directory}", where "{directory}" is the
# top-level directory to be searched. Just to be paranoid, if no directory is specified,
# then default to the current working directory ("."). Let's put the name of the
# directory into a shell variable called SOURCEDIR.
# Note: "$1" = "The first command line argument"
if test -z "$1"; then
        SOURCEDIR=`pwd`
else
        SOURCEDIR="$1"
fi

echo "Working from directory $SOURCEDIR"

# We need an empty directory to work in, so we'll create a temp directory here
cd "$WORKDIR"
mkdir "$TEMPDIR"
# and step into it
cd "$TEMPDIR"

# Now, execute a loop, based on a "find" command in the specified directory. The
# "-printf "$p|" will cause the file names to be separated by the pipe symbol, rather than
# the default newline. Note the backtics ("`") (the key above the tab key on US
# keyboards).
for CBRFILE in `find "$SOURCEDIR" -name "*.cbr" -printf "%p|while read line; do

    # Now for the actual work. First, extract the base file name (without the extension)
    # using the "basename" command. Warning: more backtics.
    BASENAME=`basename $CBRFILE ".cbr"`

    # And the directory path for that file, so we know where to put the finished ".cbz"
    # file.
    DIRNAME=`dirname $CBRFILE`

    # Now, build the "new" file name,
    NEWNAME="$BASENAME.cbz"

    # We use RAR file's name to create folder for unpacked files
    echo "Processing $CBRFILE"
    mkdir "$BASENAME"
    # and unpack the rar file into it
    7z x "$CBRFILE" -O"$BASENAME"
    cd "$BASENAME"

    # Lets ensure the permissions allow us to pack everything
    sudo chmod 777 -R ./*

# Put all the extracted files into new ".cbz" file
    7z a -tzip -mx=9 "$NEWNAME" *

    # And move it to the directory where we found the original ".cbr" file
    mv "$NEWNAME" $DIRNAME/"$NEWNAME"

    # Finally, "cd" back to the original working directory, and delete the temp directory
    # created earlier.
    cd ..
    rm -r "$BASENAME"

    # Delete the RAR file also
    rm "$CBRFILE"

done

# At the end we cleanup by removing the temp folder from ram disk
cd ..
echo "Conversion Done"
rm -r "$TEMPDIR"
```

*Oh the humanity, not posting more than two links before 10 reputation and I linked the crap out of OP.. [edit]ah.. mh-mmm.. there we go..*

[edit 2] *I removed unrar as an dependency and use p7zip instead, as it can extract rar-files.*

Comment: +1 getting you halfway over the linking restriction (and I hope you saved the old version so that you can update your post later).

Comment: For a start, you should quote the `$SOURCEDIR` (in the find command), since it may contain spaces. It is better to quote `$TEMPDIR` and `$WORKDIR` (although you set them yourself). Remove spaces before and after the `=` in `WORKDIR = "/dev/shm/"`. It should `WORKDIR="/dev/shm/"`. Also quote `$1` in `test -z $1`. Also don't parse find. Use a while loop instead, as in `find ..... | while read line; do`

Comment: @user000001 Thanks! Though I seem to get the following errors after your suggestions see script in OP, (N.B It can very well be a consequence of my noobness).    /usr/local/bin/cbr2cbzTEST: line 49: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
    /usr/local/bin/cbr2cbzTEST: line 84: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @danielpublic You misunderstood my comment. `for` is not needed anymore. The whole line should be `find "$SOURCEDIR" -name "*.cbr" | while read CBRFILE; do`. With this there is also no need to set the `IFS`. It will handle all characters in the filename (except the newline '\n' - which shouldn't be used anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You will need two checks:

1. `7z t` will test the integrity of the *archive*
2. You should also test the integrity of all the image files in the archive. You can use at tools like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this.

   A simple test would be `identify` *file* but that might read only the header. I'd use `convert` *file* `-resize 5x5 png:- > /dev/null`

   This scales the image down to 5x5 pixels, converts it to PNG and then pipes the result to `/dev/null` (discarding it). For the scaling, the whole image has to be read. If this command fails with an error, something is wrong with the image file.